# String:matchs.method something not clear

Tags: java, regex, string

Hi i was copying a code form the net,for a program but there where some isuees...
I understand everything , except this one ,please tell me everything about that...

```
".*\\d.*"
```

this is the hole code

```
public void checkS(String w){
    this.w = w;              
do{ 
    if(w.matches(".*\\d.*")){              
            System.out.println("Contains a number,try again....(ya aint 2 Pac) ");              
        } else{           
            System.out.println("Allright "+">"+w+"<"+" lets go one and start the shit...");
            runL=3;
        }
}while(runL==2);    }
```

and who do i write the thing between the [] for example if i want to search for :$"%&/ ?

Please give me a source to this topic i already search but didnt found something usefull

And if my english is bad pls Tell :D

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for `String.matches`? If so, which bit of it did you not understand? I'm not sure what you mean by " the thing between the `[]`"...

Comment: Your code doesn't have `[]` in at all, or even `[`.

Comment: Right, you've got to be careful about details like that. So, have you read the documentation?

Comment: a link to that topic in the documentation would be great....sry iam a noob here :D

Comment: You shouldn't be copying code around if you haven't even worked out how to find the javadoc for `java.lang.String`. Really, you need to take things steadily. Don't try to run before you can walk. Knowing where to find documentation is one of the first things to do when you learn a new language.

Comment: here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html     i have found it but its hard to get any information out of it ..

Comment: Well, that's one top-level doc. You want the docs for `java.lang.String`, and then find the `matches` method...

Comment: thank for that info here it is [link]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)  and that leads me to [link]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html were i finaly got my answer and thanks for than Jon Skeet ,really thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`String.matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) method performs a regular expression match. There are a number of good resources out there describing regular expressions. In this specific case `".*\\d.*"` will match anything which contains at least 1 digit `\d` anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `.*\\d.*` does the following:

`.*`: Matches zero or more (`*`) of any character (`.`)

`\\d`: `\d` matches a number but you have to add an extra '\' because in java two back slashes (`\\`) becomes one. This is called *escaping*.

`.*`: same as mentioned previously

So all in all it will match any string that has zero or more characters one number then zero or more characters after that.

Some examples:

`abasdfadsf7asdga`

`foo87980890bar`

`this is a str1ng that matches!`

`7`

Comment: very good explaind but coud you give me a example on how to check if there are characters like  !"#$%&$(&)/=&(\|€ in the string ? And how can i add more paramters like that together...

Comment: @The_BM I don't quite understand what you mean by that. Do you mean any special character?